# NFS server won't start at boot/reboot on Arch Linux ARMv7

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, nfs

I've installed Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi 3. Then installed nfs-utils to be able to mount my USB HDD on network. Started and enabled nfs-server service (`systemctl start nfs-server && systemctl enable nfs-server`).
However after reboot nfs-server won't load. Here is `systemctl status nfs-server`:

```
* nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I can start the nfs-server manually by `systemctl start nfs-server` and then it works.

system info (uname -a)

```
Linux alarmpi 4.19.37-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 3 01:14:02 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

---

how can it be resolved?

Comment: What does `journalctl --unit=nfs-server` say?

Comment: @ErikF 
**journalctl --unit=nfs-server**
`code`
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-04-30 15:51:22 EEST, end at Sun 2019-05-12 08:02:27 EEST. --
May 12 08:00:48 alarmpi systemd[1]: Stopping NFS server and services...
May 12 08:00:48 alarmpi systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Succeeded.
May 12 08:00:48 alarmpi systemd[1]: Stopped NFS server and services.

Comment: and here are logs after I've made **systemctl restart nfs-server**
[logs/link to pastebin/](https://pastebin.com/raw/RsCNv2w7)